# How can we calculate Complexity in Functional Programming

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, functional-programming

I am going through interviews for .Net Programmer Position.
One of the thing that usually interviwers ask about is : Algorithm analysis, Big-O

For example

```
private int FindBigElement(long[] inputArray)
{
    long j = 0 ;
    long temp = 0 ;
    temp = inputArray[0];
    for (int index = 1; index < inputArray.Length; index++)

            if (inputArray[j] > temp) temp=inputArray[j] ;

    return temp; 
}
```

The complexity of the algorithm is : O(n)

//In this case, I am using LAMDA Expression
Logically, I am using a loop inside where() and another loop inside .Any()

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

IEnumerable<string> results = myList.Where(s => s> myList.Any());

In this case, I am going through 

string result = myList.First(s => s> myList.Any());


string result = myList.Single(s => s> myList.Any());
```

PS: I could use .FindMax() but I just use this algorithm to showcase what I would like to do ?

In general, How can we calculate the complexity of functional programming algorithm ?

Comment: Exactly the same way. What is the difference between them? Why do you think they should be treated differently?

Comment: PS: "of functional programming algorithm" --- it's an implementation, not an algorithm. Any algorithm by itself is programming language/programming paradigm agnostic and may be implemented in any of them.

Comment: I am not asking the difference between them, but between the general solutions that are written this way. Using Lamda expression. There are other complicated scenarios like Fubonacci Suite. we can solve it with one line of code  using Lamda expression .

Comment: "anonymous functions" is just a language construction, like `for` and function definition. Why do you think that it makes the complexity determining process somewhat different? You just take the implementation and calculate it. That easy. "we can solve it with one line of code using Lamda expression". You could call your function with just one line as well: `FindBigElement(arr)`. But instead - you looked over its implementation and stated it's `O(N)`. Why don't you do the same with `LINQ` methods?

Comment: The only example that jumped in my head : Look to Scala, functional language. we can solve this problem using one line of code. But it s complicated to calculate the complexity of such algorithms : http://www.derekwyatt.org/2011/07/29/understanding-scala-streams-through-fibonacci/

Comment: it's not complicated as soon as you understand Scala's syntax (and know the optimizations the language performs well): In this case the complexity of the algorithm (*not implementation*) used in scala code is `O(N^2)`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nmallick/archive/2010/03/30/how-to-calculate-time-complexity-for-a-given-algorithm.aspx) which explains how to solve for the time complexity of an algorithm. Essentially, the complexity of an algorithm is defined by O(x)

For example, O(n) is a linear complexity algorithm. What this means is that the time it takes to complete the algorithm is linear to the amount of input that the algorithm takes. In most cases, when creating algorithms you want the algorithm to have a time complexity of O(n) or less. Or if the time complexity is 5N + 3 that means that it is done 5N times (n being the input) plus a constant of 3, which will always be executed 3 times no matter what. Usually constants are for things in the programming code that accept no input, and thus will not be used several times.

To calculate the complexity, I recommend taking a look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) section, which is a table of common time complexities, the running time in O(n) notation and an example of algorithms which have the time complexities.

Lastly, calculating the time complexity of functional programming is similar to calculating the time complexity of OOP

I hope this helped, and if you have any more questions just add a comment to this post.